# How to select multiple choices for a field in django?

Tags: django, multiple-choice

Ihave this **Actor** model on the app  called **crew**.

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Parent(models.Model):
    # name=models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True,default=None)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True,default=None)
    about=models.TextField(max_length=2000,blank=True,null=True)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class Actor(Parent):
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    photo=models.ImageField(upload_to='crew/actor')
```

i want to add this model as a foreign key into the model called **Movie** which is on the app **movie**. and also want to select multiple actors on the fiels called **starring**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from crew.models import *
from review_awards.models import *
# Create your models here.
class Movie(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True,blank=True)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=100,unique=True,blank=True)
    year=models.CharField(max_length=5,blank=True)
    language=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    poster=models.ImageField(upload_to='movies/poster')
    cover=models.ImageField(upload_to='movies/cover',null=True)
    duration=models.CharField(max_length=50,default=None)
    streaming=models.ForeignKey(Streaming,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    ott=models.TextField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    **starring**=models.ForeignKey(Actor,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='actor',blank=True,null=True)
    director=models.ForeignKey(Director,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    cinematographer=models.ForeignKey(Cinematographer,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    writer=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    based =models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    genre=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    awards=models.ForeignKey(Award,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    critic_reviews=models.ForeignKey(Critic_Review,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    audience_reviews=models.ForeignKey(Audience_Review,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    rating=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
    certification=models.ForeignKey(Certification,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    synopsis=models.TextField(max_length=1000,blank=True)
    trailer=models.TextField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

How can i implement it?, currently iam able to select only one choice.

Comment: What you're looking for is called Database Design. There are such things as ER-Diagrams and [Normal forms/Database Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) you'd probably like to google and read about. The approach you're trying to find is probably an M:M relation which can be implemented in Django by ManyToManyField. However there are more than one issues in shown model so I'd suggest to start with DB Design basics. For example `critic_reviews` in given model is a scalar value and a single move can have only 1 review. Which is not what you wanted I guess.

Comment: so how can i add multiple values on it, what changes I should make

Answer (score 0):

To allow for multiple actors in the starring field of the Movie model, you can use a ManyToManyField instead of a ForeignKey.

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from crew.models import Actor  # Import the Actor model from the crew app
from review_awards.models import *

class Movie(models.Model):


    starring = models.ManyToManyField(Actor, related_name='movies', blank=True)  # Use ManyToManyField for multiple actors
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Run migrations (python manage.py makemigrations and python manage.py migrate) after making these changes to update your database schema.

When you want to add or remove actor you can do it like this:

```py
# Assuming you have a movie object named 'movie' and an actor object named 'actor'

# Add an actor to the starring field
movie.starring.add(actor)

# Remove an actor from the starring field
movie.starring.remove(actor)
```

To show these details in the view you can have a view like this:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Movie

def movie_detail(request, movie_id):
    movie = Movie.objects.get(pk=movie_id)
    return render(request, 'movie_detail.html', {'movie': movie})
```

and in this template you can show starring like this:

```
<h1>{{ movie.name }}</h1>

<h2>Starring:</h2>
<ul>
  {% for actor in movie.starring.all %}
    <li>{{ actor.name }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, how can i display these datas on html page? I've already made a detail function, what changes i should make ?.

Comment: @Harry I edited my answer you can use the view and jinja code that I shared with you. if it helps please accept my answer as a correct answer and an upvote. it helps me too, thanks

Comment: @Harry please give an upvote and accepted answer if it helped